# How to change multiple values in the interface simultaneously?

Tags: interface

This is more about interface usage, but it will be really useful later on. Like when we want to change X, Y and Z values simultaneously. The GIF is taken from the Blender official beginner tutorial.

Any ideas on how to do this? Tried using Alt or Ctrl combination with no luck.

[image: preview]

Comment: Tried to simply shift & drag the mouse pressed over the adjacent fields, then edit the value?

Comment: No Shft, Ctrl or Alt. Simply hover mouse over the first field and left click then while still pressing the left mouse button drag down through the other fields. Release mouse button, enter value and confirm by either hitting the Enter key or left mouse click somewhere outside of the value fields.

Comment: Dragging the mouse to multiple value works! Thanks for sharing!